# PDF files downloading rather than opening in a tab

Tags: configuration, pdf

We recently upgraded to Sitecore 9 and noticed that our PDF links are now downloading rather than opening in a new tab.  I have tried changing the forceDownload in the the Sitecore.config to false, and I also uncommented the PDF line in the mime config file.  My changes are being reflected in the show config, but the PDF is still being downloaded.  Does anyone have any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: What do you mean with "uploading"? I cannot imagine that you had a site that uploaded a pdf file by clicking a link...

Comment: The Sitecore media cache is stored on disk and is valid for 90 days. If anyone has recently accessed these media items, they will not reflect the config changes. Delete the MediaCache folder in the Website directory.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say rather than opening a new tab.  I was really tired when I posted this question.

Comment: Can you confirm that the same issue happens on more than one desktop browser? https://apemobile.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001569212-PDF-files-are-downloading-instead-of-displaying-in-web-browser-or-opening-in-a-new-tab

Comment: Yes, it's happening on every desktop browser that I have tested.

Comment: I deleted the MediaCache folder, and the problem still persists.

Comment: Okay, so I have figured something out.  The two settings did work, but those files are being cached in people's browsers.  We have solved the problem by change the file name or adding a url parameter.  Thanks for the help everyone.